# Incorrect resizing of fixed element's children

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have some nested divs that aren't resizing correctly with the window in Chrome 26 (stable), but they work fine in previous versions as well as in Firefox. Before I go file a bug report, I want to make sure what I'm seeing isn't expected standard behavior that my other browsers just aren't getting right.

Using Chrome 26, try resizing your preview pane on [this Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5oRxsR1i6t6YjxppRf0P?p=preview). The `#inner` element will either shrink or expand beyond the bounds of its parent, which I do not want it to do, and which it doesn't do in previous versions of Chrome or in Firefox.

Setting my `#outer` div to absolute positioning fixes the issue—except that I need the `#outer` div fixed in place. I've also noticed that removing `position:absolute` from `#main` also fixes the problem…but I need `#main` to be absolutely positioned.

I'm at a loss as to why this is happening, or even if this is expected behavior. I need the `#inner` child to resize with its `#outer` parent, not have the `#outer` element scale independently. How can I achieve this?

**HTML/CSS**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<style>
#main {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
#container {
    min-width: 400px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}
#outer {
   position: fixed;
   border: solid 2px black;
   margin-top: 100px;
   top: auto;
   max-height: 150px;
   position: fixed;
   width: 50%;
   min-width: 400px;
   margin: auto;
   background-color: green;
}

#inner {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px gray dashed;
    position: relative;
}

</style>
<div id="main">
<div id="container">
    <div id="outer">
        <div id="inner">
            <input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the main container to `position:fixed` as shown below, it will fix the resizing issue. Don't know what effect that will have on page layout, but it is a similar look.

```
#main 
{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
    background-color:#d3fcee;
}
```